# limit # of web service requests simultaneously

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, out-of-memory

I have an Excel Add-In written in C#, .NET 4.5. It will send many web service requests to a web server to get data.  E.g. it sends 30,000 requests to web service server. When data of a request comes back,  the addin will plot the data in Excel. 
Originally I did all the requests asynchronously, but sometime I will get OutOfMemoryException
So I changed, sent the requests one by one, but it is too slow, takes long time to finish all requests.
I wonder if there is a way that I can do 100 requests at a time asynchronously, once the data of all the 100 requests come back and plot in Excel, then send the next 100 requests.

Thanks

Edit
On my addin, there is a ribbon button "Refresh", when it is clicked, refresh process starts.

On main UI thread, ribbon/button is clicked, it will call web service BuildMetaData,
once it is returned back, in its callback MetaDataCompleteCallback, another web service call is sent
Once it is returned back, in its callback DataRequestJobFinished, it will call plot to plot data on Excel.  see below

```
RefreshBtn_Click()
{
    if (cells == null) return;
    Range firstOccurence = null;

    firstOccurence = cells.Find(functionPattern, null,
            null, null,
            XlSearchOrder.xlByRows,
            XlSearchDirection.xlNext,
            null, null, null);

    DataRequest request = null;
    _reportObj = null;
    Range currentOccurence = null;

    while (!Helper.RefreshCancelled)
    {                                
        if(firstOccurence == null ||IsRangeEqual(firstOccurence, currentOccurence)) break;

        found = true;

currentOccurence = cells.FindNext(currentOccurence ?? firstOccurence);

        try
        {
            var excelFormulaCell = new ExcelFormulaCell(currentOccurence);

            if (excelFormulaCell.HasValidFormulaCell)
            {                                                                                                      
                request = new DataRequest(_unityContainer, XLApp, excelFormulaCell);

                request.IsRefreshClicked = true;
                request.Workbook = Workbook;
                request.Worksheets = Worksheets;

                _reportObj = new ReportBuilder(_unityContainer, XLApp, request, index, false); 
                _reportObj.ParseParameters();

                _reportObj.GenerateReport();
                //this is necessary b/c error message is wrapped in valid object DataResponse
                //if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(_reportObj.ErrorMessage)) //Clear previous error message
                {
                    ErrorMessage = _reportObj.ErrorMessage;
                    Errors.Add(ErrorMessage);
                    AddCommentToCell(_reportObj);
                    Errors.Remove(ErrorMessage);
                }
            }                    
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ErrorMessage = ex.Message;
            Errors.Add(ErrorMessage);
            _reportObj.ErrorMessage = ErrorMessage;
            AddCommentToCell(_reportObj);
            Errors.Remove(ErrorMessage);
            Helper.LogError(ex);
        }
    }  

}
```

on Class to GenerateReport

```
public void GenerateReport()
{
    Request.ParseFunction();
    Request.MetacompleteCallBack = MetaDataCompleteCallback;
    Request.BuildMetaData();
}

public void MetaDataCompleteCallback(int id)
{
    try
    {
        if (Request.IsRequestCancelled)
        {
            Request.FormulaCell.Dispose();
            return;
        }

        ErrorMessage = Request.ErrorMessage;
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.ErrorMessage))
        {
            _queryJob = new DataQueryJob(UnityContainer, Request.BuildQueryString(), DataRequestJobFinished, Request);
        }
        else
        {
            ModifyCommentOnFormulaCellPublishRefreshEvent();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ErrorMessage = ex.Message;
        ModifyCommentOnFormulaCellPublishRefreshEvent();
    }
    finally
    {
        Request.MetacompleteCallBack = null;
    }
} 


public void DataRequestJobFinished(DataRequestResponse response)
{
    Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action<DataRequestResponse>(DataRequestJobFinishedUI), response);
}

public void DataRequestJobFinished(DataRequestResponse response)
{
    try
    {
        if (Request.IsRequestCancelled)
        {
            return;
        }

        if (response.status != Status.COMPLETE)
        {
            ErrorMessage = ManipulateStatusMsg(response);
        }
        else // COMPLETE
        {
            var tmpReq = Request as DataRequest;
            if (tmpReq == null) return;

            new VerticalTemplate(tmpReq, response).Plot();

        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        ErrorMessage = e.Message;
        Helper.LogError(e);
    }
    finally
    {
        //if (token != null)
        //    this.UnityContainer.Resolve<IEventAggregator>().GetEvent<DataQueryJobComplete>().Unsubscribe(token);
        ModifyCommentOnFormulaCellPublishRefreshEvent();
        Request.FormulaCell.Dispose();
    }
}
```

on plot class

```
public void Plot()
{
... 
   attributeRange.Value2 = headerArray;
   DataRange.Value2 = ....
   DataRange.NumberFormat = ... 
}
```

Comment: Any minimalist code to show your problem?

Comment: Sure. Let me try to put some code together. thanks

Comment: Have you tried using Tasks[]? You can limit the number of tasks to 100 and do a WaitAll, after the wait, you can plot the data and then run another 100 again.

Comment: @user3439376  thanks for your hint. I am not familiar with tasks, will check it out. Please point to some example if you know. thanks

Comment: I would expect to see iteratioin through requests in your code. Something like `foreach(var url in requests) { getData(url) }` But I'm seeing nothing of the sort. Can you please show that part.

Comment: Saying, "give me a good example of `Tasks` (the Task Processing Library)" is a little like saying "give me a good example of lists". It's a basic part of the framework and not specific to your situation. While we can certainly show you how to use it, we need you to provide the context so we can show you how.

Comment: @GeorgeMauer thanks. There is a loop in RefreshBtn_Click, just added

Comment: Are `DataRequest` class IDisposable? Or may be `ReportBuilder` should dispose it manually? Looks like you don't free your resources.

Comment: @VMAtm thanks. Will implement IDisposable.

Comment: Also I guess we should point out that no matter what strategy you use, 30,000 requests will take a long while. Indeed, most browsers will not allow more than five requests from a page to a source at a time and I'm sure many proxies and switches have same throttling limitations.

Answer (score 3):

`OutOfMemoryException` is not about the too many requests sent simultaneously. It is about freeing your resources right way. In my practice there are two main problems when you are getting such exception:

- Wrong working with immutable structures or `System.String` class
- Not disposing your disposable resources, especially graphic objects and WCF requests.

In case of reporting, for my opinion, you got a second one type of a problem. `DataRequest` and `DataRequestResponse` are good point to start the investigation for the such objects.

If this doesn't help, try to use the `Tasks` library with `async/await` pattern, you can find good examples [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443.aspx):

```
// Signature specifies Task<TResult>
async Task<int> TaskOfTResult_MethodAsync()
{
    int hours;
    // . . .
    // Return statement specifies an integer result.
    return hours;
}

// Calls to TaskOfTResult_MethodAsync
Task<int> returnedTaskTResult = TaskOfTResult_MethodAsync();
int intResult = await returnedTaskTResult;
// or, in a single statement
int intResult = await TaskOfTResult_MethodAsync();


// Signature specifies Task
async Task Task_MethodAsync()
{
    // . . .
    // The method has no return statement.  
}

// Calls to Task_MethodAsync
Task returnedTask = Task_MethodAsync();
await returnedTask;
// or, in a single statement
await Task_MethodAsync();
```

In your code I see a `while` loop, in which you can store your `Task[]` of size of `100`, for which you can use the [`WaitAll` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd270695.aspx), and the problem should be solved. Sorry, but your code is huge enough, and I can't provide you a more straight example.

Answer (score 1):

I'm having a lot of trouble parsing your code to figure out is being iterated for your request but the basic template for batching asynchronously is going to be something like this:

```
static const int batchSize = 100;
public async Task<IEnumerable<Results>> GetDataInBatches(IEnumerable<RequestParameters> parameters) {
    if(!parameters.Any())
        return Enumerable.Empty<Result>();
    var batchResults = await Task.WhenAll(parameters.Take(batchSize).Select(doQuery));
    return batchResults.Concat(await GetDataInBatches(parameters.Skip(batchSize));        
}
```

where `doQuery` is something with the signature

```
Task<Results> async doQuery(RequestParameters parameters) {
   //.. however you do the query
}
```

I wouldn't use this for a million requests since its recursive, but your case should would generate a callstack only 300 deep so you'll be fine.

Note that this also assumes that your data request stuff is done asynchronously and returns a `Task`. Most libraries have been updated to do this (look for methods with the Async suffix). If it doesn't expose that api you might want to create a separate question for how to specifically get your library to play nice with the TPL.